Clustering multi-dimensional dataframe
I am trying to perform a cluster analysis to address the true nature of investment strategies using Python.
To do so, I performed some rolling regressions using different indices as regressors and found good values of R2 and good meaningfullness of betas.
What I want to do now is run a k-means to get different clusters, and in theory, what I expect is n clusters that include funds with similar management strategies.
I have some problem on this last step: I am using PCA to reduce the dimension of my dataset (from 8 to 2, where 8 is of course the number of betas or regressors), and then running a k-means to cluster returns (using elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters). However, results seems to be not good in the sense that funds with really different betas are in the same cluster. I tried to increase the number of clusters accepting some additional WCSS but this does not work. I think something is not working when reducing dimensionality before clustering.
Cannot provide a minimal reproducible example, but this is some of my code to let you better understand
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_X = pca.fit_transform(betas)

for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(pca_X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
kl = KneeLocator(range(1, 11), wcss, curve="convex", direction="decreasing")
best_cluster = kl.elbow
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=best_cluster)
kmeans.fit(pca_X)

Some of you already had this type of problem?

Hard to tell anything without a [mre]. We don't even know what distance you are using for clustering.

Actually don't seen any problem reduce dimension strategy. May be 2 dimension is low dimension to couldn't representation your data. You should evaluate to reducing dimension method. And PCA very well reduce dimension method to reduce dimension with preserve feature. May be k-mean clustering method may not be a good clustering method for your data. Because k-mean method is centered base method so if your data distribution may be don't suitable to cluster center based. Before determined clustering method, you should analyze your data.
